# chainWebpack - how to set infrastructureLogging

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, webpack-chain

I have `chainWebpack` section in `vue.config.js`. I

```
chainWebpack: config => {
    // Add "node_modules" alias
    config.resolve.alias
        .set('node_modules', path.join(__dirname, './node_modules'));

    config.devtool('source-map');
    // Do not remove whitespaces
    config.module.rule('vue')
        .use('vue-loader')
        .loader('vue-loader')
        .tap(options => {
            options.compilerOptions.preserveWhitespace = true
            return options
        })
}
```

I want to include `infrastructureLogging` section to redirect logging to `stdout` instead of `stderr`:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  infrastructureLogging: {
    stream: process.stdout,
  },
};
```

How can i do that in using `chainWebpack` section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`webpack-chain`](https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain) (used by `chainWebpack`) seems to not support an API for `infrastructureLogging`.

However, you could use [`configureWebpack`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#configurewebpack) to pass that option to Webpack:

```js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    infrastructureLogging: {
      stream: process.stdout,
    },
  }
}
```

Note `chainWebpack` and `configureWebpack` can be used together. Use the [`vue inspect`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#inspecting-the-project-s-webpack-config) command to see the resulting Webpack config.